# Why is shuffle write huge compared to shuffle read?

Tags: apache-spark

Lets say I have a task that joins two dataframes or rdds

```
dfA: col1, col2
dfB: col1, col3

dfA.join(dfB, dfA.col1=dfB.col1)
```

Looking at the executor summary, my max task has 1gb shuffle read and 40gb shuffle write.

There is no imbalance issue, among all the tasks the shuffle reads are similar (900mb - 1gb). I used a salted key technique to make sure the keys are spread out uniformly.

So why the 40x difference on the max task? (col1, col2, col3) is not 40x the input. So where is all that extra data going?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Its because of the groupBy step I have right after this.

The imbalance is with the groupBy key.